# Bigcommerece issue regarding save_new_account

Tags: php, bigcommerce

I want to add user in mailchimp list whenever user registerd in bigcommerece shop. I see it wil redirect on `login.php?action=create_account` url after registration but how could I put code in `create_account` function?

Can anybody give me the path of that function's file? Where i could put my mailchimp api code?

Answer (score 1):

`create_account` is not actually a function, but rather a URL query argument value that allows Bigcommerce to securely create the user account on the server. You do not have access to modify the code that creates the account.

I recommend using the free Mailchimp app that will do this for you automatically. Just install the app, authenticate your Mailchimp account, select the list you want users added to and it will do everything for you.

You can find the app here: https://www.bigcommerce.com/apps/mailchimp/